# New Google Apps Marketplace Setup URL Domain Parameter

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

It seems like a lot has changed with the new Google Apps Marketplace. I'm trying to configure a setup URL for Google to redirect the user to in order to configure an application. When using a manifest in the past I was able to specify http://whatever.com/{domain}, {domain} being a dynamic piece of data. However, the new Google Apps Marketplace SDK does not use a manifest and gives an error when I try to include {domain} in the value. How can I achieve this? The documentation is very minimal.

Comment: How are you constructing the URL in Universal Navigation Link? Try {DOMAIN_NAME}.

Comment: @jonathanberi Still does not work. I am using  http://localhost:58492/a//{DOMAIN_NAME}

Comment: Sorry, dropped a char. Try localhost:58492/a/${DOMAIN_NAME}.

Comment: @jonathanberi That worked, thanks. Where is this even documented?

Comment: I've filled a bug to get it added to the docs, thanks.

Comment: @jonathanberi Are there any other variables that can go in there?  Where is the documentation on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For followup the standard is now ${DOMAIN_NAME}